# Unity 4.3 Android, Entire Screen Not Displayed on Device

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a simple 2D game in Unity 4.3 just like the Space Shooter or Galaxy Shooter.

When I did a development build and deployed the apk file to my Nexus 4 phone, I don't see the entire screen in my phone. All of my sprites don't show up in the screen, some of them are cut off. In the unity Game Play they just show up fine.

I tried several options and solutions but they did not help me much. One of the solutions that came close to solving my problem is: http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.in/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html but still it did not solve my real problem as I need to give the aspect ration manually in this script. I am not very sure how to detect the phone's aspect ratio and tweak the script accordingly so that it can adjust for all the phones.

So, my real intention is to tweak the above script or have a simpler solution that can help me target a game to all the android devices(phones and tablets). Also I am not very much worried about the resolution. I just want my game to be visible in all the android devices the way I see it in the Game screen when I test my game in Unity.

If I am confusing you with the above explanation, I simple need my game to display in all the devices as the same way I see it in Unity while I test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its very broad question my friend...
You've to design your game for All the major standard aspect ratio's first.
For example say for **Nexus 4: Resolution = 768x1280** thus **aspect ratio is 5:3**
***Hence you should first design your game for your base aspect ratio for this case we will consider 5:3 as base aspect ratio***. Complete the game and then start its porting for all other major aspect ratios that will cover all the android devices.
 Take a look at the following pseudo code it is just for your reference only:

```
//1.3 = aspect ratio 4:3
if (CurrentAspectRatio == 1.3)
{
//Do your porting related stuff here for this particular aspect ratio
}
//1.5 = aspect ratio 3:2
if (CurrentAspectRatio == 1.5)
{
//Do your porting related stuff here for this particular aspect ratio
}
//1.66 = aspect ratio 5:3
if (CurrentAspectRatio == 1.66)
{
//Do your porting related stuff here for this particular aspect ratio
}
//etc and so on...
```